# Can't return a HttpResponse inside a def in a view

Tags: python, django

I can't seem to make my view return a HttpResponse object. I made my view to call a def depending on a attribute `choice` value. 
Here's my views.py code:

```
def assign_attribute_value(request, id_item_type):
    """

    """
    def integer_attr(item_type):
        form = forms.AssignIntegerTypeForm()
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = forms.AssignIntegerTypeForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                attr_int = form.cleaned_data['attr_int']
                item_type.attr_int = attr_int
                item_type.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/des/list_item_types/')
            else:
                ctx = {'form':form}
                return render_to_response('des/item_type/assign_attribute_value.html', ctx, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
        ctx = {'form':form}
        return render_to_response('des/item_type/assign_attribute_value.html', ctx, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

    def string_attr(item_type):
        form = forms.AssignStringTypeForm()
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = forms.AssignStringTypeForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                attr_str = form.cleaned_data['attr_str']
                item_type.attr_str = attr_str
                item_type.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/des/list_item_types/')
            else:
                ctx = {'form':form}
                return render_to_response('des/item_type/assign_attribute_value.html', ctx, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
        ctx = {'form':form}
        return render_to_response('des/item_type/assign_attribute_value.html', ctx, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

    def boolean_attr(item_type):
        form = forms.AssignBooleanTypeForm()
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = forms.AssignBooleanTypeForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                attr_bool = form.cleaned_data['attr_bool']
                item_type.attr_bool = attr_bool
                item_type.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/des/list_item_types/')
            else:
                ctx = {'form':form}
                return render_to_response('des/item_type/assign_attribute_value.html', ctx, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
        ctx = {'form':form}
        return render_to_response('des/item_type/assign_attribute_value.html', ctx, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

    def date_attr(item_type):
        form = forms.AssignDateTypeForm()
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = forms.AssignDateTypeForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                attr_date = form.cleaned_data['attr_date']
                item_type.attr_date = attr_date
                item_type.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/des/list_item_types/')
            else:
                ctx = {'form':form}
                return render_to_response('des/item_type/assign_attribute_value.html', ctx, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
        ctx = {'form':form}
        return render_to_response('des/item_type/assign_attribute_value.html', ctx, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

    type_func = {0: integer_attr,
                 1: string_attr,
                 2: boolean_attr,
                 3: date_attr,
    }

    item_type = ItemType.objects.get(id=id_item_type)
    type_func[item_type.choice](item_type=item_type)
```

Comment: You forgot to return value from view, I think: ``return type_func[item_type.choice](item_type=item_type)``

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code:

```
def assign_attribute_value(request, id_item_type):

    def integer_attr(item_type):
        ...
        return render_to_response('des/item_type/assign_attribute_value.html', ctx, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

    def string_attr(item_type):
        ...
        return render_to_response('des/item_type/assign_attribute_value.html', ctx, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

    def boolean_attr(item_type):
        ...
        return render_to_response('des/item_type/assign_attribute_value.html', ctx, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

    def date_attr(item_type):
        ...
        return render_to_response('des/item_type/assign_attribute_value.html', ctx, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

    type_func = {0: integer_attr,
                 1: string_attr,
                 2: boolean_attr,
                 3: date_attr,
    }

    item_type = ItemType.objects.get(id=id_item_type)

    type_func[item_type.choice](item_type=item_type)
```

You defined several callbacks and you are calling them, but you are not returning from the view the rendered response which was returned by any of your callbacks. Do this:

```
def assign_attribute_value(request, id_item_type):
    ...
    return type_func[item_type.choice](item_type=item_type)
```

BTW, I would suggest you putting those callbacks on a module level, to avoid compilation of them on each view call. Or use a class based view with those callbacks in separate methods.